# Curved texture on a low poly model

Tags: uv

Is it possible, without adding vertices to the model, to more accurately shape the uv of an object to match the curvature of a texture?

Example

[image]

Comment: This is not possible without adding some vertices. Looking at the screenshot you provided I'd say you'll have to add two more vertices along the curvature. You could also adjust your texture to fit the model better. It depends on what you're going for.

Comment: Also, it depends on what you need to achieve, if that curve line is sitting on a flat plane then you wouldn't really need to add any more vertices. If those 2 different areas has considerable height differences then you cannot do it without adding more details

Comment: If it is a flat surface you might want to try using curves instead of a polygon mesh.